# Phonegap - Android - localStorage data loss

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I've written an Android app using Phonegap which stores data in localStorage while 'offline' and allows the user to upload the data when GSM or WiFi are available.

Everything [normally] works fine, I've tested on a variety of phones and tablets and several versions of Android from Gingerbread to JellyBean and the app has been used by several people during trials.  BUT I've had two occasions on a Motorola XOOM2 ME running Honeycomb where all localStorage data suddenly disappears for no apparent reason.

Question #1: Anybody else having this problem, any ideas of the cause?

Question #2: Are the data still on the device somewhere and if so is it accessible?

Any clues/help would be great.

jon

Comment: Note that the user can manually clear the localStorage in the App settings

Comment: True - But in these cases I know the user hasn't fiddled with the device.  The App itself also has a 'Reset' function that clears the localStorage, but there is the normal 'Are you sure' type of check and I've been over the code path **many** times looking for bugs that would allow the reset code to be run 'by accident' and can't find any other access.

Comment: I have always found localstorage to have a unstable feel, not that there is alot of choice tho. I'm pretty sure the answer to your second question is NO.

Comment: Thanks for responding Rob, sadly not the response I was hoping for :-(

Comment: What is the data type, how are you storing it? With the Phonegap database API?

Comment: Data Type is Text.
I'm storing it with straighforward localStorage, i.e. localStorage.setItem("foo","bar")
See entry in [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite database for offline use rather than localStorage if you found any difficulty of using it